# How can I use REST API to create a node with status/tags/data

Tags: services, 8

Follow the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module document, I can only create nodes using *REST API* with *type, title* and *body*. But I am not able to create nodes with more parameters such as *tags, status* and *date*.

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

You should have look at [drupal docs](http://drupal.org/node/1354202) but for understanding that first install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module - it really helps you to discover field names.